# Set Date from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a code in VB.Net application which I would like to move to stored procedure. 
VB code looks something like this :

```
if(id == 3)
{
  var year = Year(invoiceDate)
  updatedDate = DateSerial(dueYear, DueDateMonth, DueDateDay)

  If updatedDate < invoiceDate Then
     updatedDate += 1
     updatedDate = DateSerial(updatedDate , getMonthFromDBTable, getDayFromDBTable)
  End If
}
```

This is part of a condition which I am trying to resolve.

Currently in SQL I have the following

```
DECLARE @tmpCalendarDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @tmpYear int;

SET @tmpCalendarDate = convert(varchar(10), getdate(),120);
SET @tmpYear = DATEPART(yyyy, @tmpCalendarDate);

SELECT COALESCE (
       CASE WHEN tt.ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(day, t.DaysUntilDue, r.InvoiceDate) END,
       CASE WHEN tt.ID = 3 THEN -- This is where I need to add the condition.
```

I was thinking of setting the `@tmpCalendarDate` with the values to look something like

```
CASE WHEN tt.ID = 3 THEN @tmpCalendarDate = '@tmpYear-t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay'
```

where `t` is a table.

This value cannot be changed, so I would rather calculate and fetch it once rather than calculating it every time binding changes (wpf application).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I realized maybe I am vague with my question, so here it is 
How do i set `@tmpCalendarDate`? I tried

`SELECT @tmpCalendarDate = '@tmpYear-t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay' FROM table t`

and I get an error `'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'` Instead I am expecting something like `@tmpCalendarDate` to be set to `'2016-03-12'`

Also, can I add an If..Else condition inside CASE.Then
In my example:

```
CASE WHEN tt.ID = 3 THEN @tmpCalendarDate = '@tmpYear-t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay'
    IF (@tmpCalendarDate > InvoiceDate)
    BEGIN
      --Do some logic
    END
    ELSE
      --Do some logic
    BEGIN
    END
```

Comment: I don't think I completely understand the question but couldn't you use
`CASE WHEN tt.ID = 3 THEN @tmpCalendarDate = '@tmpYear-(select t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay from yourtable where clause)`

Comment: That's not VB code. Just sayin'.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, but my question is how do i set @tmpCalendarDate? I tried SELECT  @tmpCalendarDate = '@tmpYear-t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay' FROM table t and I get an error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: Sorry, its a vb.net code. Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATEFROMPARTS`

```
@tmpCalendarDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@tmpyear, t.DueDateMonth, t.DueDateDay)
```

Your mistake in your original attempt is you are setting @tempCalendarDate to actual string `@tmpYear-t.DueDateMonth-t.DueDateDay` which results in a conversion error.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for. Also, can I have an if else condition inside a case statement?

Comment: Instead of IF. You can nest a CASE inside of a CASE. `CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN CASE WHEN....`

Comment: Thats what I tried, Thanks a lot for DATEFROMPARTS suggestion